# how to create is_role('string') function in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

the function `is_role('role')` is not defined in wordpress.

I want to write a function that compares the input string to the current user role in wordpress and returns `true` if they match and `false` if not

I have uploaded snippets plugin and tried typing some code but it did not work.

Comment: You say you "*tried typing some code but it did not work*"... please show us the code you tried and the exact problem you had with it, so we can see what you were doing and help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function:

```
function my_is_string_current_role( $string ){
    if( !function_exists( 'wp_get_current_user' ) ) return 'unknown';
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    return in_array( $string, (array) $user->roles );
}
```

Example if you are logged-in as administrator:

my_is_string_current_role('administrator');

will return true

Call the function when wp_get_current_user is available in the WordPress flow.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `current_user_can()`

Eg:

```
if current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) {
   // pass
} else {
   // false
}

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/
```